# HTML Save WebGL Canvas as Image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I am using https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr

I am trying to get the image to be saved from the following example:
https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr/blob/dev/examples/facedeform.html

The issue is that I have obviously tried `canvas.dataToURL()`. I can get the video of the webcam as an image; however, the overlay image is always transparent.

I attempted using the texture to draw on a canvas, but that also didn't work.

I have an example here: https://codepen.io/msj121/pen/RgXjYK

I want to save the whole image with overlay to a png, like "dataToURL" I suppose.

```
                // when everything is ready, automatically start everything ?

                var vid = document.getElementById('videoel');
                var vid_width = vid.width;
                var vid_height = vid.height;
                var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
                var overlayCC = overlay.getContext('2d');
                var webgl_overlay = document.getElementById('webgl');

                // canvas for copying videoframes to
                var videocanvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
                videocanvas.width = vid_width;
                videocanvas.height = vid_height;

                /*********** Setup of video/webcam and checking for webGL support *********/

                var videoReady = false;
                var imagesReady = false;

                function enablestart() {
                    if (videoReady && imagesReady) {
                        var startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');
                        startbutton.value = "start";
                        startbutton.disabled = null;
                    }
                }

                $(window).load(function() {
                    imagesReady = true;
                    enablestart();
                });

                var insertAltVideo = function(video) {
                    if (supports_video()) {
                        if (supports_webm_video()) {
                            video.src = "./media/cap13_edit2.webm";
                        } else if (supports_h264_baseline_video()) {
                            video.src = "./media/cap13_edit2.mp4";
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                        fd.init(webgl_overlay);
                        return true;
                    } else return false;
                }

                // check whether browser supports webGL
                var webGLContext;
                var webGLTestCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                if (window.WebGLRenderingContext) {
                    webGLContext = webGLTestCanvas.getContext('webgl') || webGLTestCanvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
                    if (!webGLContext || !webGLContext.getExtension('OES_texture_float')) {
                        webGLContext = null;
                    }
                }
                if (webGLContext == null) {
                    alert("Your browser does not seem to support WebGL. Unfortunately this face mask example depends on WebGL, so you'll have to try it in another browser. :(");
                }

                function gumSuccess( stream ) {
                    // add camera stream if getUserMedia succeeded
                    if ("srcObject" in vid) {
                        vid.srcObject = stream;
                    } else {
                        vid.src = (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));
                    }
                    vid.onloadedmetadata = function() {
                        // resize overlay and video if proportions are different
                        var proportion = vid.videoWidth/vid.videoHeight;
                        vid_width = Math.round(vid_height * proportion);
                        vid.width = vid_width;
                        overlay.width = vid_width;
                        webgl_overlay.width = vid_width;
                        videocanvas.width = vid_width;
                        
                        fd.init(webgl_overlay);
                        vid.play();
                    }
                }

                function gumFail() {
                    // fall back to video if getUserMedia failed
                    insertAltVideo(vid);
                    alert("There was some problem trying to fetch video from your webcam, using a fallback video instead.");
                }

                navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
                window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.msURL || window.mozURL;

                // check for camerasupport
                if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video : true}).then(gumSuccess).catch(gumFail);
                } else if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                    navigator.getUserMedia({video : true}, gumSuccess, gumFail);
                } else {
                    insertAltVideo(vid);
                    alert("Your browser does not seem to support getUserMedia, using a fallback video instead.");
                }

                vid.addEventListener('canplay', function() {videoReady = true;enablestart();}, false);

                /*********** Code for face substitution *********/

                var animationRequest;
                var positions;

                var ctrack = new clm.tracker();
                ctrack.init(pModel);

                function startVideo() {
                    // start video
                    vid.play();
                    // start tracking
                    ctrack.start(vid);
                    // start drawing face grid
                    drawGridLoop();
                }

                var fd = new faceDeformer();

                var mouth_vertices = [
                    [44,45,61,44],
                    [45,46,61,45],
                    [46,60,61,46],
                    [46,47,60,46],
                    [47,48,60,47],
                    [48,59,60,48],
                    [48,49,59,48],
                    [49,50,59,49],
                    [50,51,58,50],
                    [51,52,58,51],
                    [52,57,58,52],
                    [52,53,57,52],
                    [53,54,57,53],
                    [54,56,57,54],
                    [54,55,56,54],
                    [55,44,56,55],
                    [44,61,56,44],
                    [61,60,56,61],
                    [56,57,60,56],
                    [57,59,60,57],
                    [57,58,59,57],
                    [50,58,59,50],
                ];

                var extendVertices = [
                    [0,71,72,0],
                    [0,72,1,0],
                    [1,72,73,1],
                    [1,73,2,1],
                    [2,73,74,2],
                    [2,74,3,2],
                    [3,74,75,3],
                    [3,75,4,3],
                    [4,75,76,4],
                    [4,76,5,4],
                    [5,76,77,5],
                    [5,77,6,5],
                    [6,77,78,6],
                    [6,78,7,6],
                    [7,78,79,7],
                    [7,79,8,7],
                    [8,79,80,8],
                    [8,80,9,8],
                    [9,80,81,9],
                    [9,81,10,9],
                    [10,81,82,10],
                    [10,82,11,10],
                    [11,82,83,11],
                    [11,83,12,11],
                    [12,83,84,12],
                    [12,84,13,12],
                    [13,84,85,13],
                    [13,85,14,13],
                    [14,85,86,14],
                    [14,86,15,14],
                    [15,86,87,15],
                    [15,87,16,15],
                    [16,87,88,16],
                    [16,88,17,16],
                    [17,88,89,17],
                    [17,89,18,17],
                    [18,89,93,18],
                    [18,93,22,18],
                    [22,93,21,22],
                    [93,92,21,93],
                    [21,92,20,21],
                    [92,91,20,92],
                    [20,91,19,20],
                    [91,90,19,91],
                    [19,90,71,19],
                    [19,71,0,19]
                ]

                function drawGridLoop() {
                    // get position of face
                    positions = ctrack.getCurrentPosition();

                    overlayCC.clearRect(0, 0, vid_width, vid_height);
                    if (positions) {
                        // draw current grid
                        ctrack.draw(overlay);
                    }
                    // check whether mask has converged
                    var pn = ctrack.getConvergence();
                    if (pn < 0.4) {
                        drawMaskLoop();
                    } else {
                        requestAnimFrame(drawGridLoop);
                    }
                }

                function drawMaskLoop() {
                    videocanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(vid,0,0,videocanvas.width,videocanvas.height);

                    var pos = ctrack.getCurrentPosition();

                    if (pos) {
                        // create additional points around face
                        var tempPos;
                        var addPos = [];
                        for (var i = 0;i < 23;i++) {
                            tempPos = [];
                            tempPos[0] = (pos[i][0] - pos[62][0])*1.3 + pos[62][0];
                            tempPos[1] = (pos[i][1] - pos[62][1])*1.3 + pos[62][1];
                            addPos.push(tempPos);
                        }
                        // merge with pos
                        var newPos = pos.concat(addPos);

                        var newVertices = pModel.path.vertices.concat(mouth_vertices);
                        // merge with newVertices
                        newVertices = newVertices.concat(extendVertices);

                        fd.load(videocanvas, newPos, pModel, newVertices);

                        var parameters = ctrack.getCurrentParameters();
                        for (var i = 6;i < parameters.length;i++) {
                            parameters[i] += ph['component '+(i-3)];
                        }
                        positions = ctrack.calculatePositions(parameters);

                        overlayCC.clearRect(0, 0, vid_width, vid_height);
                        if (positions) {
                            // add positions from extended boundary, unmodified
                            newPos = positions.concat(addPos);
                            // draw mask on top of face
                            fd.draw(newPos);
                        }
                    }
                    animationRequest = requestAnimFrame(drawMaskLoop);
                }

                /*********** Code for stats **********/

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                document.getElementById('container').appendChild( stats.domElement );

                document.addEventListener("clmtrackrIteration", function(event) {
                    stats.update();
                }, false);

                /********** parameter code *********/

                var pnums = pModel.shapeModel.eigenValues.length-2;
                var parameterHolder = function() {
                    for (var i = 0;i < pnums;i++) {
                        this['component '+(i+3)] = 0;
                    }
                    this.presets = 0;
                };

                var ph = new parameterHolder();
                var gui = new dat.GUI();

                var presets = {
                    "unwell" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    "inca" : [0, 0, -9, 0, -11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    "cheery" : [0, 0, -9, 9, -11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    "dopey" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0],
                    "longface" : [0, 0, 0, 0, -15, 0, 0, -12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -7, 0, 0, 5],
                    "lucky" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4, 0, -6, 12, 0, 0],
                    "overcute" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, -14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    "aloof" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 10],
                    "evil" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8],
                    "artificial" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, -16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    "none" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                };

                var control = {};
                var eig = 0;
                for (var i = 0;i < pnums;i++) {
                    eig = Math.sqrt(pModel.shapeModel.eigenValues[i+2])*3
                    control['c'+(i+3)] = gui.add(ph, 'component '+(i+3), -5*eig, 5*eig).listen();
                }

                /********** defaults code **********/

                function switchDeformedFace(e) {
                    //var split = ph.presets.split(",");
                    for (var i = 0;i < pnums;i++) {
                        ph['component '+(i+3)] = presets[e.target.value][i];
                    }
                }

                document.getElementById('deform').addEventListener('change', switchDeformedFace, false);

                for (var i = 0;i < pnums;i++) {
                    ph['component '+(i+3)] = presets['unwell'][i];
                }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason the webgl canvas is blank has been answered at least 10 times here on stackoverflow

- [Saving canvas to image via canvas.toDataURL results in black rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556939/saving-canvas-to-image-via-canvas-todataurl-results-in-black-rectangle?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Canvas toDataURL() returns blank image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783586/canvas-todataurl-returns-blank-image-only-in-firefox)
- [toDataURL() of webgl canvas returning transparent image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710748/todataurl-of-webgl-canvas-returning-transparent-image)
- [Why does my canvas go blank after converting to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538193/why-does-my-canvas-go-blank-after-converting-to-image)

I know there's several more but I'm too lazy to search for all of them

The only reason I didn't mark this as a duplicate is because you wanted 1 png from 2 canvases.

If you want just 1 png then you need to capture from one canvas. So, draw the WebGL canvas into the video canvas then call `toDataURL` on the video canvas.

```
const vctx = videocanvas.getContext('2d');
vctx.drawImage(webGLTestCanvas, 0, 0); 
const capturedImage = videocanvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Sadly, although setting {preserveDrawingBuffer:true} works, in this case it causes major visual flaws. I currently cannot accept this answer as it breaks the whole application. It leaves lots of previous frames on the canvas as the canvas is much larger than what is being drawn. Perhaps a clearRect would work?

Comment: Yes, clearing the image worked with gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT. Thanks for the links, for the record I did search stackoverflow but came up with other approaches

Comment: The solutions linked did not say you need to use `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`. They specifically said you do **not** need to do that. On top of which the solution I posted above, drawing the webgl canvas into the videocanvas also does **not** need `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`

Comment: I have tried this solution, but 2d canvas still empty (I trying "copy" image from webgl to 2d canvas)

Comment: This two canvas trick doesn't work anymore, only thing that worked for me was using `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`.

Answer (score 2):

Most of what I've seen requires `{preserveDrawingBuffer: true}` when initializing your canvas. In my case, I was working on a project where using this had poor side effects that kept the canvas from properly clearing between drawing frames.

I was able to get around this by re-drawing everything on the current frame immediately before calling `toDataUrl()`.

This managed to fix my problem and I've been able to get consistently accurate URLs using a WebGL canvas. While it's not a perfect solution, I thought I'd share since there doesn't seem to be many other workarounds out there.

Comment: fyi but that exact answer is in the linked answers