# How to save WebGL canvas as PNG in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl

I need to save a canvas element as a png image for automated tests. The problem is that data is placed in `webgl` context so solution like [How to save a canvas as PNG in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316402/how-to-save-a-canvas-as-png-in-selenium) doesn't work for me (blank image is returned).

I looked trough some questions (i.e. [HTML Save WebGL Canvas as Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221542/html-save-webgl-canvas-as-image)) and understood that `webgl` context data is available only before rendering or `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` is required. But I'm testing this game and can't modify it.

I may have missed how I can save WebGL canvas as PNG. I would appreciate any advice.

P.S. Taking page screenshot is not solution for me because it takes too much time (up to 10 seconds for some old mobile devices).

**UPD1:**

@LJᛃ I tried [Canvas toDataURL() returns blank image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783586/canvas-todataurl-returns-blank-image) in console:

```
# find my canvas element
canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")

# run 2 commands from question above
canvas.getContext('webgl', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(origFn) {
  return function(type, attributes) {
    if (type === 'webgl') {
      attributes = Object.assign({}, attributes, {
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
      });
    }
    return origFn.call(this, type, attributes);
  };
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext);

# trying to get data, but it returns blank image
canvas.toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);
```

But it still return blank image. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How about overriding `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext` with a version that always sets `preserveDrawingBuffer` to `true` ?

Comment: @LJᛃ Could you please explain what do you mean? I've just updated question with the option I tried

Comment: You have to override `getContext` before the application uses it so basically as soon as possible.

Comment: @LJᛃ I've already tried it as I showed in question (ran this code in browser console) and it didn't work for me. Is this what you suggest?